# Reverse radial axes of Matplotlib polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, reverse, astronomy

I'm trying to create an astronomical polar plot with a radial axis that starts from -45° on outer line and increases to 90° in the center of the plot. But I didn't find any way to reverse radial axis of the PolarAxes instance. `invert_yaxis()` method doesn't work at all. Also, there are some *hidden* methods such as `ax.set_rlim()` that doesn't have any docs.

Here is my current code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8], polar=True)
# ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_ylim(-45, 90)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-45, 90, 15))
ax.plot(ras, decs, linestyle='', marker='.')
```

and my plot

[image]

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075001/set-radial-axis-on-matplotlib-polar-plots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit "hacky", but if you know the bounds (which it seems like you do as it corresponds to declination) you could do something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8], polar=True)
# ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_rlim(90, -45, 1)
# Note: you must set the end of arange to be slightly larger than 90 or it won't include 90
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-45, 91, 15))
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks()[::-1])
ax.plot([0,10,20], 90-np.array([12,13,14]), linestyle='', marker='.')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It looks OK, but the actual axis is still the same - look at the values. So we also need to convert them too.

Comment: This does not answer the question, points still have to go under a coordinate change to be printed the right way.

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but I finally found an easy answer. Use `ax.set_rlim(bottom=90, top=-45)`. Note that you have to set this BEFORE calling `ax.plot()`, or it will not transform the plotted points accordingly.

Comment: Much easier than the accepted answer and works perfectly.